# how to add search index to sqlite database in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I'm new to programming and I need to add a search index to a SQLite database. Does any body know of a tutorial and can someone point me in the right direction as I have been unable to find any info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean, like full-text search? You're on your own, SQLite doesn't do that for you (whereas MySQL and Postgres, for example, do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can grab some amalgamation code from [SQLite web-page](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and compile it with additional modules. But this advice will be useful only if you know how to do such stuff.